# ER diagram to relational schema with two relationships between two entites

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have an ER diagram like this - 
[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbnwk.jpg)

and I have to convert this to relational schema

so far I have this - 
Employee (Employee_id, ssn, salary, phone)
Child (child_id, name, age, Employee_id)

between Departments and Employee, I am not sure if I should create an extra entity, or if I should insert the employee_id into the Departments? The reason I am stuck is because they have two relationships `<work in>` and `<manage>`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rule for you to consider:

1. How many Employees can a single Dept manage?
2. How many Depts can a single Employee work for?

If the answer to (1) is more than 1, then there is a 1 to Many relationship in this direction. If the answer to (2) is more than 1, than there is also a 1:M relationship in the opposite direction. Thus, there is a many-to-many relationship between the entities and you need an extra entity (say, Employment) to maintain this relationship in the database.

Btw, if you insert `employee_id` into the Departments your answer to (1) is "no more than 1", which is probably incorrect. If you insert `dept_id` into Employees your answer to (2) is "no more than 1", which is more reasonable.
Lastly, the number of relationships shown in the ER diagram does not necessarily translate to the number of physical instances (tables) one should create.

Hope this helps

Comment: HI Anton, thanks for your help first.
Here is the situation:
Employees work in departments; each department is managed by an employee. 
Each employee works in exactly one department.

So it is going to be "many to one" and "one to one" relationship, I believe.

The reason I was thinking to create an extra table was because, there are 2 relationships in between these 2 entities. I have no idea how to present them in a right way.

Comment: Hey @Peter. I see, yeah, two relationships... So "each department is managed by an employee" translates to `manager/employee_id` in Depts, and "Each employee works in exactly one department" translates to `dept_id` in Employees. You don't need a separate entity to maintain these relationships

Comment: Thanks Anton. For-" "each department is managed by an employee" translates to manager/employee_id in Depts"...how do I present if the employee is a manager in the schema prospective? For the second one"Each employee works in exactly one department" translates to dept_id in Employees."<-- this is clear now, appriciated!!

Comment: > how do I present if the employee is a manager in the schema prospective? Not sure I understand "schema perspective". In the ER diagram this is presented as a (second) separate relationship (e.g. "manages dept"). In the physical db schema this fact is presented by a `manager_id` field in Dept table that (if you like to enforce it) has a foreigh key reference to `employee_id` (primary key) in Employee. I.e. `manager_id` column will contain an id of the employee who manages this dept

Comment: Hi Anton, if I convert this into this, does it make sense at all?
Employee (Employee_id, ssn, salary, phone, Department_id)

Departments (Department_id, dno, dname, budget, Manager_id)

Child (child_id, name, age, Employee_id)

The Manager_id has a foreign key ref to Employee_id (primary key) in Employee

Comment: Yes, I think this reflects the structural rules you stated above